# SQL Server Casting performance

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, query-performance

In a query, I am casting an nvarchar datatype to numeric(precision, scale).
Below is the query -

```
SELECT FIELD_VALUE,
  FREQUENCY_COUNT
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.FIELD_KEY = T2.FIELD_KEY
INNER JOIN Table3 T3
ON T3.FUNCTION_KEY       = T1.FUNCTION_KEY
WHERE T3.PROFILE_RUN_KEY = 65
AND T2.FIELD_NAME          = 'DEPT_ID'
AND
  CASE
    WHEN T2.IS_VIRTUAL = 0
    THEN T2.RECORD_NAME
    ELSE T1.RULE_NAME
  END = 'EMPLOYEES'
ORDER BY FREQUENCY_COUNT DESC,
CAST(FIELD_VALUE AS NUMERIC(4,0)) DESC;
```

The performance of this query was too low.
Upon doing some random hit and trial, I had changed the casting part like this - CAST(FIELD_VALUE AS NUMERIC) and the performance got improved.

Can anyone please explain the reason behind this?(Let me know if some more info is required)

The tables used here have less than 100 rows.Some of the field values are null too.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be interesting to see where exactly the system does the conversion. Probably it's near the end, meaning this only happens on less than 100 rows then. I'm surprised to learn that would give even a measureable difference.

The 'implicit' conversion will convert `FIELD_VALUE` to a Numeric (18, 0) which takes 9 bytes, in contrast to your explicit conversion that results in a Numeric (4, 0) which takes 5 bytes.

Although both 9 and 5 are 'off' numbers, it's hard to believe that 
 * the conversion itself makes much of a difference
 * sorting a list of 100 * 5 bytes is slower than sorting a list of 100 * 9 bytes

I tried to reproduce your findings like below, but could not find any differences in duration. (Estimated sizes differ slightly but that's as expected). If it doesn't show up with 100k rows than I'm having a hard time believing it would be with 100 rows...

Could it be you're seeing the effect of caching and wrongfully attribute it to the

```
    SET STATISTICS TIME ON

IF OBJECT_ID('t_test') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE t_test

SELECT TOP 100000 FIELD_VALUE = Right(Convert(nvarchar(100), BINARY_CHECKSUM(NewID())), 4)
  INTO t_test
  FROM sys.objects, sys.columns, sys.types
GO
SELECT FIELD_VALUE
  FROM t_test
 ORDER BY CAST ( FIELD_VALUE AS NUMERIC(4, 0))
GO 3
SELECT FIELD_VALUE
  FROM t_test
 ORDER BY CAST ( FIELD_VALUE AS NUMERIC)
GO 3
```